# Downgrade from Freeform Pro to Freeform - Error

Tags: solspace-freeform

Not needing all the features of Freeform Pro I attempted to downgrade to the regular version of Freeform 4.0.12. However, when I attempted to run the update script I get the following error:

> An Error Was Encountered
>   Unable to load requested field type file: ft.freeform.php.
>   Confirm the fieldtype file is located in the expressionengine/third_party/ directory

What do I need to get rid of this error and get up and running on FF?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought that you had solved the problem, but in reality I had to go into yet another table and remove all the Freeform Pro-specific fieldtypes. It is the exp_freeform_fieldtypes table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You likely need to remove the entry for `freeform` from your `exp_fieldtypes` database table.

Comment: Thanks for the fix here, Derek. This is a bug, however, and we have filed it.