# Error when trying to access a channel from the backend

Tags: add-on, fieldtype

Good evening!

I was wondering if anyone has seen this issue before.  Whenever I try and access the backend details of a channel, I'm getting this php error:

```
Error: Unable to load requested field type file: ft.calendar.php.
Confirm the fieldtype file is located in the /system/user/addons/ directory
```

Has anyone ever seen this one before?

Thanks for anybody's thoughts.  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a file from an add-on, most likely [Solspace Calendar](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/calendar/). You will need to verify the installation of that add-on is complete, and correct for your version of EE (which is either 3 or 4). The missing file would be `/system/user/addons/calendar/ft.calendar.php`.

The other option is to remove the add-on, but this can be dicey if you already have an incomplete installation. To manually remove it, you'll need to go through several database tables (at least `exp_actions`, `exp_extensions`, possibly `exp_plugins`, `exp_fieldtypes`, and maybe even others) and remove reference to it. If you have the calendar field as an actual field in any channel, this gets even more complex to remove properly.

So go with the first option of verifying the installation and proceeding from there.

Comment: For "calendar" this resolved that error.  I guess I'd also tried out Solspace' s "freeform" at one point as well.

For that one, I had to edit exp_fieldtypes, per:

https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13626/downgrade-from-freeform-pro-to-freeform-error

Really appreciate it.